# Why is the nitrate concentration in a root hair cell higher than the nitrate concentration in soil?

Tags: cell-biology, plant-anatomy, membrane-transport, minerals

For the exchange of nitrates and other mineral ions to occur between the root hair cell and the soil, the root hair cell needs a higher concentration of mineral ions and nitrates than the soil so that active transport can happen from the soil to the root hair cell. Please can someone explain how and why the root hair initially has more nitrate ions than the soil and what the point of absorbing these minerals is if the root hair cell already has more?

Sorry if this questions is worded badly or some of the information is wrong.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146360/discussion-on-question-by-arya-08-why-is-the-nitrate-concentration-in-a-root-hai); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.